# How to start/restart the remote desktop service on windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, remote-desktop

As I understand it there is a remote desktop service that should be listening on port 3389, which should be visibile using this command: `netstat -ano | findstr 3389`. How do I start or restart it in Windows 8?

Comment: Start > Programs > Admin Tools > Services and then start "Remote Desktop Services"?

Comment: @DavidPostill If I recall correctly it won't show there unless you have first enabled it once via the "properties" panel of "My Computer". (And if you do that the service gets set to "automatic"  startup and gets started too. After that it can be stopped/started through regular services.) ... And it doesn't exist at all on Home Editions ? (Never used Home so I wouldn't know.)

Comment: @Tonny Well I have it (Windows 7 Home Premium)

Comment: @DavidPostill I'll take your word for it. I haven't used any Home edition for many years. At the Office it's all Pro, Enterprise and Server and the 1 Windows box I have at home (the rest are Mac's) is a refurbished business box that came with Pro as well.